# Struggling to understand a complex join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Below is my query

```
SELECT cover.id              AS cID,
       cover.title           AS cTitle,
       cover.slug            AS cSlug,
       cover.image           AS cImage,
       cover.timestamp       AS cTimestamp,
       category.name         AS catName,
       category.slug         AS catSlug,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag.tag) AS tags
FROM   cover
       JOIN category
         ON cover.category_id = category.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_tag
         ON cover_tag.cover_id = cover.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tag
         ON tag.id = cover_tag.tag_id
GROUP  BY cover.title
LIMIT  0, 30
```

This will return all covers and all tags for each cover. Now, what if I want to return only rows that have a tag 'cars' BUT still return all tags the cover has?

I'm trying to find help on Google but have no idea what I am searching for.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you're asking,

```
SELECT cover.id              AS cID,
       cover.title           AS cTitle,
       cover.slug            AS cSlug,
       cover.image           AS cImage,
       cover.timestamp       AS cTimestamp,
       category.name         AS catName,
       category.slug         AS catSlug,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tag.tag) AS tags
FROM   cover
       JOIN category
         ON cover.category_id = category.id
       JOIN cover_tag
         ON cover_tag.cover_id = cover.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tag
         ON tag.id = cover_tag.tag_id
       JOIN tag T2
         ON T2.id = cover_tag.tag_id AND T2.tag = 'cars'
GROUP  BY cover.title
LIMIT  0, 30
```

The last join should ensure that the cover_tag has a tag called 'cars'.

**EDIT** Hm, better explanation... A picture? Over 9000 words saved, they say. The matched structure for a cover with a tag set of "photos, cars, great" would be:

```
                     [cover] ---- [category]
                        |
                        |
                        |
[tag:photos] ----/ [cover_tag] ---- [T2:cars]
[tag:cars]   ---/
[tag:great]  --/
```

For a cover with a tag set of "clown, shoes, balloon, kids_love_it", `T2` would not match, thus `cover_tag` would not match, thus `cover` would not match.

Comment: The `tags` result only returns the tag 'cars'. I need it to return all the tags each Cover has, but only return results that include the tag 'cars'

Comment: Yeah, read again. The table `tag` is joined twice, one of those under an alias. It is `T2` row which needs to be `'cars'`, not the `tag` we're using for results. This restricts `cover_tag`, and then `tag` table picks up all the tags contained in that `cover_tag`.

Comment: Also, [what I imagine when I see "catslug"](http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2010/337/9/4/catslug_by_twistedornot-d3446va.png)...

Comment: Still a little confused. I understand what you mean, but not sure where to go from here. I need to find a good book that can help with these sorts of SQL joins. Things start to get tricky and I'm easily lost in SQL.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yeah, and I actually edited it to make it explicit. I need to restrict the resultset to those where `T2` matches something, which can't happen in any rows where an inner join would differ from a left one. Now that I think of it, the other left join doesn't make any sense either since it too will have at least one element (`'cars'`).

Comment: My original left outer joins were included because I copied the query from my last one and altered it. But, looking at it now it made no sense. Originally the left outer joins were to include `covers` that had `null` tags (some `covers` have no tags). But in this case a `null` would be pointless. Amaden your explanation is great but the issue here is my knowledge of joins. I'll do some reading and come back to this.

Answer (score 1):

Does adding this do the job?

```
HAVING INSTR(CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT(tag.tag),',') , ',Car,') > 0
```

Comment: that's a fun way to solve the problem, but i can't imagine this being scalable.  perhaps that isn't a concern for the op.  +1 for creativity though.

Comment: Yep probably better to have two joins on the `tag` table.

Comment: Depends on the scale, obviously. If it's a toy project with 100 lines, this solution is definitely easier to understand. But if there's even a glimmer of possibility it would get big...

Comment: Yes, this project will defiantly expand over time, which is why I didn't choose this solution. I also like to understand and learn about an problem I'm having trouble understand. But thanks anyway Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a 2-query problem, resulting in separate sets of data. Then we find the intersection of those 2 sets.

You've already got the 1st set: "all tags for (all) covers". The second set "Covers with tag-value 'cars'" would be the same as your original query w/ a WHERE clause added, filtering for the tag-value "cars".

Now, to combine the two. The technique highlights:

+The second query goes in a "where exists" (or "not exists" as desired)

+The second query filters on the specific value

+The primary key from each instance of the "central" table is part of that filter

```
SELECT c1.id AS cID, c1.title AS cTitle, c1.slug AS cSlug, c1.image AS cImage, c1.timestamp AS cTimestamp, cat1.name AS catName, cat1.slug AS catSlug,       GROUP_CONCAT( t1.tag ) AS tags
FROM cover c1
JOIN category cat1 ON c1.category_id = cat1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_tag ct1 ON ct1.cover_id = c1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag t1 ON t1.id = ct1.tag_id
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *    -- what we select is irrelevant. We only care that the row exists
        FROM cover c2
        JOIN category cat2 ON c2.category_id = cat2.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cover_tag ct2 ON ct2.cover_id = c2.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tag t2 ON t2.id = ct2.tag_id
        WHERE
            t2.value = "cars"
            and c1.id = c2.id
    )
GROUP BY c1.title
LIMIT 0 , 30
```